# Floating box under input

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm developing a website and per requeriments, there's one thing I can't manage to figure out the best way to implement.

http://www.bodas.net/ Take a look at this website. You can see there's a search form in the front page, the "c00l" thing about it, is that **once you click on the field ("¿Que Buscas?"), it pops up a list of "suggestions".** Or categoryes about related stuff.

**I'm trying to accomplish the same behaviour**, but avoiding loadings (*I already have the information to be shown beforehand*). I believe it could be accomplished by CSS and hidden divs or bootstrap. The thing is, I do not know how to accomplish that. How to popup a floating box under the exact position of the input box.

Could someone give me an example? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: A quick way to check how it is done is to inspect the element in Chrome Browser and get the css used. Check this floating div box with the css class="SelectorOptions droplayer droplayer-extralarge multi-column"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work for you.

With only css. Basically we have a wrapper div `.bar` that holds the input and the popup. The popup has `display:none` and when you focus the input it appears.

Also, the popup has `position: absolute` being always relative to the wrapper div `.bar`.

```css
.popup {
  display: none;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 20px;
}
.foo:focus + .popup {
  display: block;
}
.bar {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <input type="text" class="foo">
  <div class="popup"></div>
</div>
<div class="bar">
  <input type="text" class="foo">
  <div class="popup" style="background-color: gray;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe this should work beautifully, and it should be fine to add animations or transitions on how those hidden boxes appear. Thanks, I thought it would be somethinig similar to this but lacked the selectors and positioning knowledge.